# Retrofit: Only @Query is working but @Field is not working

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services, annotations, retrofit

I am tried to insert the data using `@Field` and `@Body` with `@POST` but it generates `"500 internal server error"` and same code I tried with `@GET` and `@Query` then it works correct and data inserted successfully.

So is there any way to insert data using `@Body` or @Field to my asp.net web-site using web service web method.

```
Using @Body


 @POST("/EducationApi.asmx/addEducationAPI")
    public void addEducation(@Body Education education, Callback<Education> callback);
'''

Using @Field

'''
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/EducationApi.asmx/insertEducationAPI/")
    public void insertEducationDetail(@Field("user_id") int user_id, @Field("degree_name") String degree_name, @Field("institute_name") String institute_name, @Field("board_university_name") String board_university_name, @Field("year_of_passing") int year_of_passing, @Field("percentage_cgpa") float percentage_cgpa, @Field("specialization") String specialization, Callback<Education> callback);


using @Query (This works proper)


@GET("/EducationApi.asmx/insertEducationAPI")
    public void insertEducation(@Query("user_id") int user_id,@Query("degree_name") String degree_name, @Query("institute_name") String institute_name, @Query("board_university_name") String board_university_name,@Query("year_of_passing") int year_of_passing,@Query("percentage_cgpa") float percentage_cgpa,@Query("specialization") String specialization, Callback<Education> callback);
```

I want to use `@Post` to insert the record to my database

Comment: Should `/EducationApi.asmx/insertEducationAPI/` be having slashes at the end ?

Comment: Are you able to post to the API using postman?

Comment: In postman also 500 internal server error occurs with @Field

Comment: yes Slashes is their

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/EducationApi.asmx/insertEducationAPI/")
public void insertEducationDetail(@Field("user_id") int user_id, @Field("degree_name") String degree_name, @Field("institute_name") String institute_name, @Field("board_university_name") String board_university_name, @Field("year_of_passing") int year_of_passing, @Field("percentage_cgpa") float percentage_cgpa, @Field("specialization") String specialization, Callback<Education> callback);
```

I have done a silly mistake with the above code. That's why it is not working so change the above code to below code

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/EducationApi.asmx/insertEducationAPI")
public void insertEducationDetail(@Field("user_id") int user_id, @Field("degree_name") String degree_name, @Field("institute_name") String institute_name, @Field("board_university_name") String board_university_name, @Field("year_of_passing") int year_of_passing, @Field("percentage_cgpa") float percentage_cgpa, @Field("specialization") String specialization, Callback<Education> callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes It is Possible to Send Data With Body. Inside Body You can send @Field and @query or Multi-part Data as per Your Choice.**

See Below Code Here I create On Class which merge @Field and Multi-part data for image upload and send all this data through Body.

```
public void addConactList(String name, String vessel, String email, String phone, String country, String note, String selectedfilename, ByteArrayOutputStream bos, String bvalue, String pvalue, String intrested) {
    RetroFitService retroFitService = RetrofitClient.getSalesLead();

    MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM);

    builder.addFormDataPart(Const.Name, name)
            .addFormDataPart(Const.Vessel, vessel)
            .addFormDataPart(Const.Email, email)
            .addFormDataPart(Const.Phone, phone)
            .addFormDataPart(Const.Country, country)
            .addFormDataPart(Const.Notes, note)
            .addFormDataPart(Const.Photo, selectedfilename, RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, bos.toByteArray()))
            .addFormDataPart(Const.Business, bvalue)
            .addFormDataPart(Const.Probability, pvalue)
            .addFormDataPart(Const.Interest, intrested);


    RequestBody requestBody = builder.build();

    try {

        Call<ContactResponse> call = retroFitService.addCountryList(requestBody);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ContactResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ContactResponse> call, Response<ContactResponse> response) {
                ContactResponse msg = response.body();
                Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: " + msg.toString());
                listener.onAddContact();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ContactResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.toString());
                listener.onAddContact();
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Then after i call this class file Method from my activity using Below Code.**

```
new AddContactDetails(context, this).addConactList(name, vessel, email, phone, country, note, selectedFileName, bos, bvalue, pvalue, intrested);
```

**You Have to Post body method in Retrofit Service Class like below code.**

```
 @POST(Const.Add_Contact)
Call<ContactResponse> addCountryList(@Body RequestBody file);
```

Comment: @POST(Const.Add_Contact)------- what this line means and please also show me the web method (ASP.NET weeb services) and RequestBody class (Android) code which you have written for help.

Comment: Const.Add_Contact is a variable which store my api file name. you can simple write @Post("Your Api File Name")

Comment: will you please add the web service code (asp.net  side)